# Read all the labels inside the div using jquery / javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have one div which has labels some hidden and some showable.

I want to read all the labels which is not hidden.

Example:

```
<div id="demodv">
<label id="lbl_1"></label>
<label id="lbl_2" style="display:hidden"></label>
<label id="lbl_3"></label>
<label id="lbl_4" style="display:hidden"></label>
<label id="lbl_5"></label>
<label id="lbl_6" style="display:hidden"></label>
<label id="lbl_7"  style="display:hidden"></label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`:visible`](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) pseudo-class selector.

```
$('#demodiv label:visible')
```

```js
console.log($('#demodv label:visible').length)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="demodv">
  <label id="lbl_1">1</label>
  <label id="lbl_2" style="display:none">1</label>
  <label id="lbl_3">1</label>
  <label id="lbl_4" style="display:none">1</label>
  <label id="lbl_5">1</label>
  <label id="lbl_6" style="display:none">1</label>
  <label id="lbl_7" style="display:none">1</label>
</div>
```

---

**UPDATE :** But it would treat empty elements(elements which don't have any child nodes) as hidden so use [`filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) method if you want to include them.

```
$('#demodv label').filter(function() {
  return this.style.display != 'none'
})
```

```js
console.log($('#demodv label').filter(function() {
  return this.style.display != 'none'
}).length)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="demodv">
  <label id="lbl_1"></label>
  <label id="lbl_2" style="display:none"></label>
  <label id="lbl_3"></label>
  <label id="lbl_4" style="display:none"></label>
  <label id="lbl_5"></label>
  <label id="lbl_6" style="display:none"></label>
  <label id="lbl_7" style="display:none"></label>
</div>
```

---

**FYI:** There is no `hidden` value for [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) property in CSS. For hiding element we are using `none` as the property value

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log($('#demodv label:not([style="display:hidden"])').length)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="demodv">
<label id="lbl_1"></label>
<label id="lbl_2" style="display:hidden"></label>
<label id="lbl_3"></label>
<label id="lbl_4" style="display:hidden"></label>
<label id="lbl_5"></label>
<label id="lbl_6" style="display:hidden"></label>
<label id="lbl_7"  style="display:hidden"></label>
</div>
```

Use something like this:

1. Select using attribute which is not hidden.